# Wpf application with entity framework not working on other systems. Showing error 50

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I have made an application in `wpf .net 4.5` using `entity framework` with `Database sqllocaldb` I published the app from visual studio 2015 it work fine on my PC but it doesn't work on other (client) pc

**My Connectionstring is**

```
 <connectionStrings><add name="SETDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\SETDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

**I have also checked**
because i checked some answers they give the solution by putting database into some folder but not worked in my case.

```
<connectionStrings><add name="SETDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Db\SETDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

I have installed localDb from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb) on other system

 I have also add a prerequisite of sql   
 [image]
But also not work 
 I also Tried to install Manually sqllocal db but also not working 
Here is the Exception

[image]

**EDIT :-**
When i tried to start sqllocaldb from cmd on client system it shows error
[image]

Any Suggestion or solution how to solve the problem 
Regards

**Solution:-**

- Install/Reinstall the compatible version of sqllocaldb with windows and use
  MSSQLLocalDB for instance.
- If MSSQLLocalDB Doesn't work as auto Instance than make a new
  instance of sqllocalDB and start it manually. It Will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make sure that SQLServer is installed and working

open the CMD or PowerShell and type "sqllocaldb info" it should return the instance name try also type "sqllocaldb start" to run it

use this library to handle it from your app 
https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb

Comment: I have checked MSSQLLocalDb run when my app is not running but it shows error while my app is running . if i use this git hub library i have to start and stop connection manually on my app start and close ?

Comment: try this as your connection string                     

"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SETDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"

Comment: Its a start issue sqllocaldb doesn't start the instance automatically . i have tried to start it from cmd it shows BCryptKeyDecryption could not located in the bcrypt.dll

Comment: yes i reinstall the sqllocalDB compatible with Windows and run it manually it worked . Hope it will work and make auto instance. The issue is only sql server is not running on other pcs.

Comment: u can use the library above to control your existed instance or to create a new ones (create start stop delete etc)

@Ahmad SQlServer Express 2017 LocalDB i think it needs dotnet core sdk to run on windows 7

use 2014 or 2012

Comment: yes you are right it need dotnet core now i am using 2014.